# How to deselect all tabs on app starts

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitabbarcontroller

This used to work for previous iOS4.3, but since iOS 4.3+ that cause the app to crash:

```
((UITabBarController*)self.parentViewController.parentViewController).selectedViewController = nil;
```

The line above is in `viewDidLoad` method and it's responsible for deselecting the first tab so that all tabs look unselected, why it's causing my app to crash now? is there an way for iOS5+ to do the same. All tabs are managed by a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? How is the user supposed to know which controller he's looking at when the app starts if none of the tabs are selected?

Comment: Actually I am displaying a separate `UIImageView` which remain on the screen and which doesn't belong to any tab, so I need all tabs to be unselected at start :)

Comment: If you want to display an image, why not present a modal controller (without animation) from the viewDidAppear method of the controller in the first tab -- this will cover the whole screen, including the tabs.

Comment: I had that idea, but the requirements of the app I am working on is like this, cannot hide all tabs by a modal view.